# If $x$ and $y\in\Bbb{R}^{n}$ are eigenvectors for $\lambda\neq\mu$, respectively, show $x^{T}\cdotp y = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, transpose

For $x^{T}\cdotp y = 0$, I understand that I can either look at it through matrix multiplication $x^{T}y^{T} = 0$ as you can't do that multiplication. I'm very sure this isn't the right way of looking at it but am unsure how else to think about proving this.

Comment: "Are eigenvectors" makes no sense - you mean they are eigenvectors of $A$. Now what you say you want to prove is _false_. Look at the problem again, and give  a correct statement, without leaving anything out.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Im saying that x is an eigenvector for $\lambda$ and y is an eigenvector for $\mu$

Comment: I understood that. Saying $x$ is an eigennvector for $\lambda$ makes no sense! _Square matrices_ have eigenvectors and eigenvalues, and there is no matrix here. Once you fix that,  by saying you're talking about some matrix $A$, it makes sense but it's false. Wrong.  Incorrect. Untrue.

Comment: You evidently saw my first comment. It's simply incredible that you can't take the time to look at the exercise again and tell us what the exercise actually says!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The exercise word for word states "Q2: Let A be a symmetric n × n matrix over R.
(i) Prove that all eigenvalues of A are real.
(ii) Let x and y ∈ R
n be eigenvectors for ${\lambda} {\neq} {\mu}$, respectively. Show that x
T
· y = 0.

Comment: **Look:** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$. Let $x=(1,0)^T$, $y=(1,1)^T$, $\lambda=1$, $\mu=2$. Then $Ax=\lambda x$, $Ay=\mu y$, but $x^Ty\ne0$.

Comment: I knew that's what the exercise stated! Why didn't you say so? First, it makes sense,  while your questino doesn't,,  because it specifies a matrix $A$. Second, if you leave out the fact that $A$ is symmetric the result is false.

Comment: Right? It was pretty heavily implied given the question, topic and tags.

Comment: For heaven's sake. If the reader has to look at the tags to _guess_ what the question _states_ then it's a bad bad bad question. It's _still_ a hugely bad question, btw. Note the "edit" link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the question is unclear, speaking of eigenvalues and eigenvectors without mentioning a matrix. For some reason the OP is unwilling to fix the question.

A reader not already familiar with the correct version of the result in question might get the impression we want to prove this:

> > **False Fact** If $A$ is a square matrix, $Ax=\lambda x$, $Ay=\mu y$ and $\lambda\ne \mu$ then $x^Ty=0$.

Of course that's false: Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$, $x=(1,0)^T$, $y=(1,1)^T$.

The correct version is this:

> > **True Fact** If $A$ is a symmetric square matrix, $Ax=\lambda x$, $Ay=\mu y$ and $\lambda\ne \mu$ then $x^Ty=0$.

This is easy. First, the whole point to symmetric matricies:

> > **Lemma.** If $A$ is symmetric then $x^TAy=y^TAx$.

Proof: Since a $1\times 1$ matrix is its own transpose and $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ we see that $$x^TAy=(x^TAy)^T=y^TA^Tx=y^TAx.$$

Having established that the True Fact is easy:

$$0=x^TAy-y^TAx=\mu x^Ty-\lambda y^Tx=(\mu-\lambda)x^Ty,$$which implies that $x^Ty=0$, since $\mu-\lambda\ne0$.